# Run script on UNIX socket message received

Tags: bash, sockets, unix

I can see messages sent to a **Unix socket file** by redirecting them to a terminal output:

```
socat /home/user/mpvsocket /dev/pts/0
```

I would like to run a **script** when I receive a specific message on that socket.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What prevents you from just reading the socket in a loop, looking for that specific message, and then do something, like running a script? What have you tried so far?

Comment: How do I read the socket in a loop? Does socat support reading to stdout?

Comment: I love people who downvote for fun.

Comment: See the `EXEC` "address type" in the man page. And here for an example: https://blog.rootshell.be/2010/10/31/socat-another-network-swiss-army-knife/

Comment: @GilHamilton If it executes an instance for every message it is perfect. I'll try it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Gil Hamilton who suggested me a link with an exemple of the EXEC option of socat which I modified:

Run socat:

```
socat <PathToSocket> EXEC:<PathToScript>,fdin=3,fdout=4
```

Content of the script:

```
while read -u 3 BUFFER
do
    if [ "$BUFFER" = "<MessageImWaiting>" ]; then
        # Some actions triggered by the message.
        echo "<ResponseToTheEvent>" >&4
    fi
done
```